# How can I define dev & production ENV using express & mysql2?

Tags: node.js, express, mysql2, node-mysql2, jawsdb-maria

I found some other similar answers to this, but I was not confident in my ability to comprehend and get it right, so I'm hoping to get a little validation on my approach if it's right, seeing as what i've cobbled together is from a tutorial. I've also included the requires, as I'm not actually calling express in this file (db.js) but it is used in other places:

(PS. I am deploying to Heroku, and using JawsDB as my production DB)

```
require("dotenv").config();
const mysql = require("mysql2");
//const { DatabaseError } = require('pg');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
});
```

and this is what i'm thinking of doing:

```
app.configure('production', function(){
    app.locals.URLs = {
        const pool = mysql.createPool({
             host: process.env.DB_HOST_LOCAL,
             user: process.env.DB_USER_LOCAL,
             database: process.env.DB_NAME_LOCAL,
             password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL,
    }
});
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.locals.URLs = {
        const pool = mysql.createPool({
             host: process.env.DB_HOST_JAWS,
             user: process.env.DB_USER_JAWS,
             database: process.env.DB_NAME_JAWS,
             password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD_JAWS,
    }
});
```

is this right, and will I need to require `app = require('express')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject anything into express (router, middleware, configuration, template engine, etc) then you're gonna need "app". With [locals](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#app.locals) you are creating a "URLs" property inside your app instance.

This is not a big deal but you could instead `module.exports = pool;` as an independent js module and use it regardless of Express.

About your env, be cautious no to leak production passwords into development nor a developer's local configuration into production. That said you don't need a if.. else for your configuration. I also spot you don't have an env configuration for tests...

[Here in the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) the prefered way to load your vars is by **preloading** them.

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js
```

You can also customize your .env file if you enjoy `.env.local` `.env.production` `.env.test` approach

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/.env
```

This also allows you to have multiple settings without worry of conflicts / unintended overrides or leftovers.
You could also

- inject individual variables via [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)
- inject production variables via [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/)